# Hyper-V machines unable to receive external packets - name resolution/host machine work fine

Tags: hyper-v, timeout

Running into a problem which has me at my limits, unfortunately. I've set up a home lab consisting of the following:
- host machine running Server 2012 evaluation
- Watchguard router (layer 3 boundary)
- multiple virtual machines

The server is configured to provide DHCP, DNS, Hyper V, etc. That's all well and good - I successfully performed a WDS deployment of a Windows 7 image onto the virtual machines. Connectivity between the host and client is flawless. Likewise, the host machine has a normal, working connection to the internet.

However, my virtual client machines - all of them, I've tried multiple - are unable to receive external packets. They will resolve domain names according to the DNS server I've set up, and I can see the traffic in the Wireshark session I have running on the host. For some strange reason, the client machines just won't receive external traffic. For example, NSlookup finds everything as it should, and ping/tracert resolve the IP of any name you put in - but any requests they send time out.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? I've already checked firewalls, gone over my DNS records, etc. - nothing seems amiss.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of virtual switch did you create for the virtual machines?

Comment: @joeqwerty External, bound to the physical NIC.

Comment: Are the VM's in the correct subnet? Are they configured with the correct Default Gateway?

Comment: @joeqwerty For simplicity's sake, I'm only using one subnet (255.255.255.0), and they're on it. The VMs are assigned addresses via DHCP, which is providing the correct gateway (10.0.1.1, my Watchguard).

Comment: 255.255.255.0 is your subnet mask. Are the VM's on the 10.0.1.x subnet? Can you tracert from a VM to the gateway?

Comment: @joeqwerty My mistake, misread. Yes, the VM's are 10.0.1.4, 10.0.1.5, etc. A tracert from the client to the gateway is only one 1 MS hop and it reaches it fine.

However - I just noticed that, in Wireshark, I do not see anything hitting the gateway if I ping it from the VM, which is odd because the VM reports receiving an ICMP echo even though, according to Wireshark, the gateway's not even seeing it.

Comment: For future reference, you can run tcpdump on Watchguard firewalls and get Wireshark compatible output, which would probably tell you what's going on. See: http://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/wsm/xtm_11/en-US/index.html#cshid=en-US/fsm/log_message_learn_more_wsm.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be the layer 3 boundary, which I had originally dismissed since the gateway was configured to pass all packets regardless of destination/origin (just for testing purposes, of course). However, upon replacing the Watchguard with a Cisco VPN firewall configured with the exact same settings, traffic is flowing normally.